# eBPF: TC on egress how to recognize and ignore the packet that is replied by TC on ingress directly?

Tags: ebpf

The TC on egress unexpectedly catch the packet that TC on ingress replied directly.

TC on egress how to recognize and ignore the packet that is by TC repled on ingress directly rather than produced by userspace app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution would be to **mark** your packet from your first program (on the ingress side), and then to look up for the mark on the egress side.

You could mark your packet on the ingress side by writing either to the `skb->mark` or one of the `cb` fields in your eBPF program, such as `skb->cb[0]`. You can later read from the same fields in your egress program.

The `mark` field (*generic packet mark*) of the socket buffer is used by applications to mark a packet (iptables may use it for some use cases, for example). The five entries in the `cb` (*control buffer*) array are also free to use by applications, to pass user-defined marks or values.